# custom authenticate function does not accept third argument

Tags: django, authentication

trying to write my own custom authentication backend using the following as a guideline:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

I want to implement the authenticate function with the following elements:

1. username
2. password
3. verification_code

I define the function as follows:

```
def authenticate(self, username=None, password = None, verification_code = None):
    ...
```

However I only get a value for `username` and `password`, did  not for `verification_code`.

The login form looks as follows:

```
<form id="login-form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
... 
    <input id="user_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Email Address" required="" autofocus="" />
    <input id="password"  type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required=""/>   
    <input id="verification_code" type="text" class="form-control" name="verification_code" placeholder="Verification Code" required=""/>  
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>   

</form>
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

As of Django 1.11 you must also include the `request` parameter:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

> Changed in Django 1.11: The `request` parameter was added to `authenticate()` and support for backends that don’t accept it will be removed in Django 2.1.